# Ubuntu 13.04 Mouse buttons not responding (events do not fire correctly)

Tags: 13.04, mouse, button

After I start Ubuntu my mouse buttons don’t work in applications. When I use the left and right mouse button in the Ubuntu interface they work fine. But when I try to use them inside an application (Firefox, libreoffice) they will not respond. Does anyone have a solution or any ideas on how to get my mouse to work inside of applications?

I’m running Ubuntu 13.04 x64 from an USB drive.  (I have tried installing Ubuntu 13.04 & 12.04 on my hard drive before while having the same problem)

I’ve had the opportunity of testing 4 different USB mice.

•   Mad Catz R.A.T 9 (wireless)

•   Razor black widow (wired)

The two other mice I’ve tested where basic Logitech USB mice.

Edit:
I just downloaded XUbuntu 13.04 x64 (I do not know how much of a driver difference it would make). While testing the left mouse button barely worked. Only after clicked the right mouse button a number of times until the drop down menu showed up the left mouse button would respond. It made no difference whether or not i was clicking inside an application or on the default interface.

Edit 2:
I just did some testing using xev. I did this using one of the newer mice and one of the basic Logitech ones. Both did show the same problem this time and the problem occurred in both the Ubuntu interface and inside applications. Below i added the information xev provided on mouse click.

```
ButtonPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x284, subw 0x3a000002, time 777837, (44,33), root:(1693,85)
state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x284, subw 0x3a000002, time 777970, (44,33), root:(1693,85)
state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x284, subw 0x3a000002, time 778819, (44,33), root:(1693,85)
state 0x0, button 3, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x284, subw 0x3a000002, time 778958, (44,33), root:(1693,85)
state 0x400, button 3, same_screen YES
```

Edit 3: I redid the testing i did inside a virtual machine (which doesn't show any mouse problems). With this i got the following results:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x3a00002, time 373889, (47,51), root:(1154,251),
state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x0, time 373889, (47,51), root:(1154,251),
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
focus YES, state 256

KeymapNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x0
keys: 101 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
      0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x3a00002 time 374010, (47,51), root:(1154,251),
state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x0, time 398758, (47, 51), root:(1154,251),
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
focus YES, state 0

ButtonPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x3a00002, time 398757, (47,51), root:(1154,251),
state 0x0, button 3, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x0, time 398758, (47,51), root:(1154,251),
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
focus YES, state 1024

KeymapNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x0
keys: 101 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
      0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x3a00002 time 398898, (47,51), root:(1154,251),
state 0x400, button 3, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
root 0x165, subw 0x0, time 398898, (47, 51), root:(1154,251),
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
focus YES, state 0
```

For some reason the EnterNotify, keymapNotify and LeaveNotify events aren't fired when I'm running Ubuntu outside of a virtual machine. Does anyone have any idea's on why those events aren't fired?

Comment: Just adding this as a comment in case someone is still looking for a solution to this problem:

Since posing this question I've had multiple installations of different Linux systems, what seems to fix the problem on all installations is lowering the polling rate of the mouse to 250Hz (down from 1000Hz). However I did not test this with and identical installation to the one before, which means it could also have been solved in a bugfix on the other systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem with my R.A.T 7. Everything works fine when testing but after installation the mouse buttons and scroll wheel simply do not work in applications. Its like it is locked to the first application opened.

After rebooting without the RAT 7 (totally unplugged from USB) and using my Wireless Microsoft 1000 everything works perfectly.

This seems to be a well known issue that has been around for some time and effect all the RATS (3,5,7,9 and MMO7). There are several sites out there most referring to changes to the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

Making these changes worked perfectly for me in 12.04 but in 13.04 I first had to get the actual mouse name again.

The following posts helped me:
http://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/using-the-cyborg-r-a-t-7-with-ubuntu/
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/All_Mouse_Buttons_Working

Hope this helps.