# Does the Microsoft Classic Intellimouse work on Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, mouse, compatibility

### the question

For my Ubuntu system, I would like to get a Microsoft "Classic Intellimouse," which is the updated version of my all time favorite "Intellimouse Explorer 3.0" (and probably the only computer-peripheral in existence with an official *"the legend reborn"* bumper-sticker).

The question is, will this mouse work with Ubuntu, or will it cause issues like those described below? Unfortunately, I could not find any information about its compatibility with Ubuntu.

### the reason for asking

When I first installed Ubuntu 18 LTS on my system, I encountered all kinds of strange issues, such as some windows (or individual buttons) and dialogs not responding to mouse clicks, whereas other windows/dialogs did respond. Maybe similar to e.g. [Ubuntu 16.04 - Mouse moves but cannot click](https://askubuntu.com/q/902811), [Mouse click not working on open apps](https://askubuntu.com/q/237557), [Ubuntu 13.04 Mouse buttons not responding (events do not fire correctly)](https://askubuntu.com/q/319384)

Also the Ubuntu software updater appeared to freeze for no apparent reason, and some dialogs did not become visible (e.g. when I changed my dual screen layout, the confirmation dialog did not appear, causing the layout to revert after a number of seconds).

As it turned out, these issues were all caused by the mouse I was using at the time: a Cyborg R.A.T. 3

After plugging in a Logitech M-BT83  (basic 3-button), all these issues were instantly resolved.

However, going from 5+ buttons to 3 is not a solution for the long term.

Comment: Yeah [the RAT3 is *exceptionally* buggy](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mad_Catz_Mouse). Still, pretty ballsy to go and buy the IntelliMouse because "[\[Microsoft\] says the rodent won't work at all with Android, iOS, or macOS](https://node2.techreport.com/news/32735/microsoft-classic-intellimouse-is-a-modern-take-on-an-old-favorite)" which is usually code for "we've done some stupid software-based mode-setting so we can change the colours when the weather changes". *dons flat cap*... I remember when mouse manufacturers just focused on making the hardware good.

Answer (score 5):

The only option was to try it out, so I bought one and...
Yes, it appears to work perfectly (at least, I have not encountered any issues yet...), on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with GNOME 3.28.2.
System specs: AMD A10-5800k with Samsung SSD.

Comment: Wow. Talk about taking it to the next level. You *bought* one???

Comment: Well... Yes. Living on the edge, right? ;-)